# Can not get multi_query() to work

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

EDITED: Working code below!

```
//* opens a connection to a MySQL server */
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$query = "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing','testing2222');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing3333','testing44444');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing5555','testing66666');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing77777','testing888888');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing99999','testing101010');";


if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                //printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
     /* print divider */
    //if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
    //  printf("-----------------\n");
    //}
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

BAD CODE below:

I've tried this every way possible and I can't seem to get it to work. I notice one variation would work only if I had one $query to input. If it ever had more than one, it would fail.

```
//* opens a connection to a MySQL server */
$mysqli = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password, $database);



$query  = "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing','testing2222')";
$query  .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing3333','testing44444')";


if($mysqli->multi_query($query))
 { 
    do
    {

        if($result=$mysqli->store_result())
        {
            while($row=$result->fetch_row())
            {
                printf("%s<br/>",$row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }

        if($mysqli->more_results())
        {
            print("-------------------------------<br/>");
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
 }
```

It makes a connection, I just trimmed some of the code to make it easier to follow. Table exist, etc... Tried the main example also, word for word, and it doesn't seem to work. Where are I going wrong?

Comment: Try to use not existing table in one of your "INSERT" statement to see how the script will react. I mean, you should not use scripts without error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `;` on the end of each statement. Also always check for errors `$mysqli->error`.

Now your query will look exactly like this

```
INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing','testing2222')INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing3333','testing44444')
```

which isn't correct.

Comment: what statement is missing a ;??

Comment: @BrianV. Your first insert.

Comment: @BrianV. - it's not your PHP code that's missign semi-colons, it's the SQL statement.

Comment: @BrianV. You shouldn't modify your question/code because of it being solved. Others who may potentially visit this question, won't know where the problem originally was, unless the see the edit. Thus, rendering my answer as being incomplete, including the other one also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wrong code is still there, with description, so where is problem?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's solved, but you posted about question edit. So I answered that edit is definitely ok.

Comment: @ElonThan It's not good practice to edit a question with the solved code inside it. It needs to remain intact. If the OP wants to post it as a seperate answer, then he/she can do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semi-colon at the end of each query. MySQL is waiting for the end of the statement. See the following from MySQL documentation:

> A command need not be given all on a single line, so lengthy commands that require several lines are not a problem. mysql determines where your statement ends by looking for the terminating semicolon, not by looking for the end of the input line. (In other words, mysql accepts free-format input: it collects input lines but does not execute them until it sees the semicolon.)

Change this:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing','testing2222')";
$query  .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing3333','testing44444')";
```

to this:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing','testing2222');";
$query  .= "INSERT INTO `test` (test1, test2) VALUES('testing3333','testing44444');";
```